# Swagger Body Parameters Returns 400 "Extra formData parameter(s) name not in spec"

Tags: python, pycharm, yaml, swagger, connexion

Am having trouble sending body parameters via Python-2.7, connexion & Pycharm.

**api.yaml**

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  title: Products Api Backend
  version: "1.0.0"
consumes:
  - application/json
produces:
  - application/json
paths:
  /products:
    post:
      operationId: app.addProduct
      parameters:
      - name: body
        description: Product payload to add
        in: body
        required: true
        schema:
          $ref: '#/definitions/ProductParameters'
      responses:
        200:
          description: Data received and added correctly
          schema:
            type: string
definitions:
  ProductParameters:
    description: Needed attributes for each post request
    properties:
      name:
        type: string
        description: Product name
```

**app.py**

```
import connexion

api = connexion.api

def addProduct(name):
   return 'Product Added'   # or 'Product Added', 200

app = connexion.App(__name__)
app.add_api('api.yaml', strict_validation=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=8092, debug=True)
```

Running

```
r = requests.post(appUrl, data={'name':'Product title here'})
print r
print r.content
```

returns

```
<Response [400]>
{
  "detail": "Extra formData parameter(s) name not in spec", 
  "status": 400, 
  "title": null, 
  "type": "about:blank"
}
```

The YAML validates in [Swagger Editor](http://editor.swagger.io/#/), but running Send Request gives

```
ERROR Method Not Allowed
Headers
undefined
Body
```

Changing addProduct() s return to

```
'Product Added', 200
```

still returns 400, so the problem's evidently at the connexion level.

Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

I forgot to turn the Python dictionary into a string (for the body), so

```
import json
dataDict = {'name':'Product title here'}
dataStr = json.dumps(dataDict)
r = requests.post(appUrl, data=dataStr)
```

returns 200

Python dictionaries are used for sending form data; body data needs sending as a JSON string.